# Migrating test cases & defects from Quality Center to TFS 2008/2010

Tags: testing, tfs, hp-quality-center

Tool that can be used to migrate (or even better..synchronize) test cases and bugs between:

TFS 2008 and Quality Center 9.2 (or later)
TFS 2010 and Quality Center 9.2 (or later)

I am aware of the following tools:

[Test Case Migrator (Excel/MHT) Tool](http://tcmimport.codeplex.com)
[TFS Bug Item Synchronizer 2.2 for Quality Center](http://onroad.juvander.fi/Community/files/)

Also shai raiten mentions on his blog about QC 2 Team System 2010 migration tool that he has been working on and its done. But could not find any link for downloading the tool.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/12/31/quality-center-migration-to-team-system-2010-done.aspx

Before jumping on coding with TFS SDK and QC components to come up with my own tool I need some inputs from the stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Scrat](https://web.archive.org/web/20110106044700/http://www.sela.co.il:80/scrat/), Migrate FULL HP Quality Center projects to TFS 2010.

Migration of all QC elements (Requirements, Bugs, Test Cases, Attachments, History and Links between items) to TFS 2010 and their interrelationships links, Fully customizable (you decide what and how to migrate each item) or fully mirrored migration (migrate everything ‘as-is’).

[Another option to get data from Quality Center into TFS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/another-option-to-get-data-from-quality-center-into-tfs/)

If you got any other questions please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I follow your blog so I already knew this :)  Awesome blog btw.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Quality Center Synchronizer](http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc90/sync/qcsynchronizer/index_9_2.html), it can be used to sync defects and requirements out of Quality Center.

And now it even support synchronization of QC Defects with TFS, for QC 9.2 take a look at [this site](http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc90/sync/qcsynchronizer/index_9_2.html), and [here](http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc100/sync/qcsynchronizer/index.html) for QC 10

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is too late.  But if not then you may want to look at the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/).

I don't know if it has an adapter created for Quality Center. But it is made to do just what you want to do (migrate and synchronize between TFS and some other tracking system).

They have several adapters made and an API for making new ones.  I would advise using that API rather that just rolling your own.